# Is there a better way to efficiently export a lot of classes as an array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export

I have a file structure like this:

```
index.ts
folder/
  a.ts
  b.ts
  subfolder/
    c.ts
    d.ts
    e.ts
    ...
```

Each file has one class in it as the default export and I want index.ts to export all the classes as an array. The way I'm currently doing it is:

```
import a from "./folder/a";
import b from "./folder/b";
import c from "./folder/subfolder/c";
import d from "./folder/subfolder/d";
import e from "./folder/subfolder/e";
...

export const things = [a, b, c, d, e, ...];
```

but with a large number of files this takes up a lot of lines and seems extremely inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why exactly an array? Are you iterating it somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can create index.ts in subfolder directory and export all ts files after that you can create a index.ts in folder directory. You can export your a.ts b.ts and subfolder index file. Finally, you can reach classes with just one import.